# how to get result of group by with join

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am using query in controller:

```
$data = DB::table('circulate_files')
           ->join('regionmasters','circulate_files.region_id','=','regionmasters.id')
           ->select('circulate_files.unique_id_for_group,circulate_files.title','regionmasters.region', DB::raw('group_concat(region) as new_region'))
           ->groupBy('unique_id_for_group')
           ->get();
```

But I am getting error:

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'circulate_files.unique_id_for_group,circulate_files.title' in 'field list' (SQL: select `circulate_files`.`unique_id_for_group,circulate_files`.`title`, `regionmasters`.`region`, group_concat(region) as new_region from `circulate_files` inner join `regionmasters` on `circulate_files`.`region_id` = `regionmasters`.`id` group by `unique_id_for_group`)**

Comment: Probably you are missing quotes. Update `'circulate_files.unique_id_for_group,circulate_files.title'` to `'circulate_files.unique_id_for_group','circulate_files.title'`

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'stqc_velocis.circulate_files.title' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `circulate_files`.`unique_id_for_group`, `circulate_files`.`title`, `regionmasters`.`region`, group_concat(region) as new_region from `circulate_files` inner join `regionmasters` on `circulate_files`.`region_id` = `regionmasters`.`id` group by `unique_id_for_group`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in your select, it should be:

```
select(['circulate_files.unique_id_for_group','circulate_files.title','regionmasters.region', DB::raw('group_concat(region) as new_region')])
```

the problem was in this code:

```
->select('circulate_files.unique_id_for_group,circulate_files.title', ...)
```

it should be:

```
->select('circulate_files.unique_id_for_group','circulate_files.title',...)
```

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'stqc_velocis.circulate_files.title' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `circulate_files`.`unique_id_for_group`, `circulate_files`.`title`, `regionmasters`.`region`, group_concat(region) as new_region from `circulate_files` inner join `regionmasters` on `circulate_files`.`region_id` = `regionmasters`.`id` group by `unique_id_for_group`)

Comment: this is an another error, it says: you should include all the columns you select except the aggregate one in your group by clause

Comment: try : groupBy(['circulate_files.unique_id_for_group','circulate_files.title','regionmasters.region'])

Comment: But now, output is not coming as I need.

Comment: I need region in comma separated value.

Comment: If I do, In config/database.php

Change 'strict' => true To 'strict' => false

Comment: then it works and giving perfect answer. Is it right way?

Comment: it 's a walk around to cancel strict query, you should avoid this choice unless if you have to

Comment: Can U please help me to find the my results?

Comment: if you want to show column in the result without include it in your group by, canceling strict query is your only solution

Answer (score 0):

**you can rewrite your query as follow and use `selectRaw` instead of `select`:**

```
$data = DB::table('circulate_files')
           ->selectRaw('
               circulate_files.unique_id_for_group, circulate_files.title, 
               regionmasters.region, group_concat(region) as new_region
            ')
           ->join('regionmasters', 'circulate_files.region_id', 'regionmasters.id')
           ->groupBy('unique_id_for_group')
           ->get();
```